# java unable to get value of static variable from the same class

Tags: java, android, static, constants, static-methods

I have a `AppConstants` class where I have some static variables and static methods. Variable like

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.somevalue.com/api/";
private static String MID_FIX_API;
public static final String API_CALL = BASE_URL + getMidFixApi() + "/" + GET_KEY(appContext, KEY_FOR_KEY);
```

As `MID_FIX_API` is private so I have its public getter/setter.
When I set its value from another class by its setter method `AppConstants.setMidFixApi("value");` and get its value from its getter method `AppConstants.getMidFixApi();` Everything is fine till now
**But**
The problem comes when after the above lines I call static variable `API_CALL` shown in the code above that get value from the getter of the variable `MID_FIX_API` and return null despite of that we have passed value to it before.

This is the whole sequence of lines

```
AppConstants.setMidFixApi("getCategories");   // setting value
Log.e("InsideSuccess", "MID_FIX_API = " + AppConstants.getMidFixApi());  // working fine till here

Log.e("InsideSuccess", "API_URL = "+AppConstants.API_CALL);   // here I'm getting like this http://www.somevalue.com/api/null/somePostFix
```

Please point me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: API_CALL is a compile time constant.

Comment: Thanks +1 for all the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned the variable `API_CALL` is initialized once, with the current value of `MID_FIX_API` which initially is null.

A work around is to create a static method (`getApiCall()`) which just computes the value which earlier was staticly initialized, which would just look as easy as this:

```
public static String getApiCall(){
    return BASE_URL + getMidFixApi() + "/" + GET_KEY(appContext, KEY_FOR_KEY);
}
```

Which then can be called in an easy manner `AppConstants.getApiCall()`.

Answer (score 1):

This has to to with initialisation order. When you call `AppConstants.setMidFixApi("getCategories")` the AppConstants class will be initialised *before* the value is set. Hence when the `API_CALL` is initialised, the `MID_FIX_API` is not yet assigned...

Comment: so I need to change `API_Call` value too while calling `AppConstants.setMidFixApi("getCategories")`?